# Populate a Vector in Scala

Tags: scala, vector

I am new with `Scala`.

I have a `Vector` in a class called `Sentence`:

```
val tree: Option[Vector[Node]]
```

The constructor of this class receives an `Array[String]` of words. For each word, I have to create a `Node` object (A class I've created), and then populate the `Vector` with all the nodes.

I am trying to fill the `tree`, but I am having problems writing the code. I have tried using:

```
private val tree: Option[Vector[Node]] = 
    words.foreach(w => new Node(w, 9, "d", 0))

private val tree: Option[Vector[Node]] = 
    words.foreach(w => tree :: new Node(w, 9, "d", 0))
```

I've also tried with `map`, but it does not work.

How could I, for each word, create a `Node` and add it to the `Vector`?

**NOTE**: If you need more code, tell me and I update the question.

Comment: `foreach` returns `Unit` so it will not work for sure. Also, your `tree` is of type `Option[Vector[Node]]` and you want to just put `Nodes` in it. EDIT: Jean posted an on-point answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
// map each word to a Node
val tree: Array[Node] = words.map(w => new Node(w, 9, "d", 0))
```

If you want a `Vector`:

```
val treeVector: Vector[Node] = tree.toVector
```

The `Option` does not bring much since it is equivalent to an emty `Vector`.

Comment: Thanks!, this did the trick: `private val tree: Vector[Node] = words.map(w => new Node(w, 9, "d", 0)).toVector`

Comment: Is there a way in which I could do a map using two variables? something like this: `(words, tags).map((w,t) => new Node(w,t,"d",0))` ?

Comment: If the contents of words and tags are synchronised (so the nth element of words relates to the nth element of tags) you can use words.zip(tags) which makes a new sequence of corresponding pairs, and then you can make as you ask, e.g.
words.zip(tags).map((w,t) => new Node(w,t,"d",0))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `foreach`. And for an `Array[A]`, `foreach` has the signature `def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit`. Here the return type of argument function `f` is `Unit` which means it is not supposed to return anything and just do something ( like print ) with each element in your array.

What you are looking for is a `map` which has signature `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Array[B]`. Here the return type of argument function `f` is `B` which means it is supposed to return an instance of type `B`. So for each element of type `A`, `map` will apply `f` to compute an instance of type `B`.

```
val newArray: Array[Node] = words.map(w => new Node(w, 9, "d", 0))

val newVector: Vector[Node] = newArray.toVector

val optVector: Option[Vector[Node]] = Option(newVector)

// Or

val optVector = Option(words.map(w => new Node(w, 9, "d", 0)).toVector)
```